# Test null object in Junit/Hamcrest

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, powermockito, hamcrest

I have an method I would like to test as follows:

```
public void fooAction(){
    if(foo != null){
        foo.doSomething(someString);
    }
}
```

My test looks like:

```
@Test
public void testFooAction(){
    mTestClass.fooAction();
    mfooClass = new Foo();
    verify(mFooClass).doSomething("");
}
```

This passes but I would also like to test when Foo is null:

```
@Test
public void testFooActionNullFoo(){
    mTestClass.fooAction();
    PowerMockito.spy(mFooClass.getClass());
    doNothing().when(mFooClass).doSomething(""));
    mfooClass = null;
    assertNull(mFooClass);
}
```

This also passes but the coverage is half only. So my question is how would I confirm that when foo = null I wanted to test that nothing should be done.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Please paste full class and test code to be able to help

Comment: Nothing is relevant to this unit test. I am doing unit test, so I don't see any reason to share my other code.